# texstudio error: miktex-maketfm did not succeed

Tags: xetex, miktex, texstudio

I trying to compile a pdf on texstudio that use xelatex and getting following error on the message console:

```
Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\nj2511\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log Process exited with error(s)
```

To solve the problem, I uninstalled texstudio, installed miktex,updated packages from the miktex console and re-installed texstudio.

Installation directory of miktex: C:\Users\nj2511\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
Installation directory of texstudio: C:\Program Files\texstudio

Then I updated the configuration tab of texstudio as follows:
[image]

I am not sure what went wrong. It would be very helpful if you kindly guide me to approach this problem.Below is the logfile of miktex-maketmf

```
2023-12-20 14:03:20,119-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm - running on Windows 10.0.22621
2023-12-20 14:03:20,127-0500 INFO  maketfm - Making OT.tfm from C:\Users\nj2511\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts/source/public/othello\OT.mf...
2023-12-20 14:03:20,128-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2023-12-20 14:03:20,129-0500 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; nonstopmode; "input OT"
2023-12-20 14:03:20,129-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm.core - start process: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; nonstopmode; "input OT"
2023-12-20 14:03:20,497-0500 INFO  maketfm - METAFONT failed for some reason
2023-12-20 14:03:20,497-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - METAFONT failed on OT.
2023-12-20 14:03:20,497-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - METAFONT failed on OT.
2023-12-20 14:03:20,497-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info: 
2023-12-20 14:03:20,497-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source: 
2023-12-20 14:03:20,497-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 0
2023-12-20 14:03:20,515-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm - this process (29512) finishes with exit code 1
```

An example of the code below:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%% CREATE DOCUMENT STRUCTURE %%%%%%%%
%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{subfig}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=.7cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm, portrait]{geometry}

%\usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{"নং - \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
%\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Bangla MN}
%\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Kohinoor Bangla}

%table of contents
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 


%\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, 
%           banglattfont=Akaash
%           ]{latexbangla}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}           
\usepackage{array,multirow}



\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newcommand{\tabnotes}[2]{\bottomrule \multicolumn{#1}{@{}p{0.70\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize #2 }\end{tabular}\end{table}}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %thickness of line under header
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}}}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{marvosym}

%math
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{carolinablue}{rgb}{0.6, 0.73, 0.89}
\definecolor{palecornflowerblue}{rgb}{0.67, 0.8, 0.94}


%color box
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{commonstyle/.style={boxrule=0pt,sharp corners,enhanced jigsaw,nobeforeafter,boxsep=0pt,left=\fboxsep,right=\fboxsep}}
\newtcolorbox{mycolorbox}[1][]{commonstyle,#1}
\newlength\myboxwidth
\setlength{\myboxwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}

%underlining text, wrapping lines 
\usepackage{ulem}
\hyphenpenalty=-50000

\usepackage{wrapfig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{right=2cm,left=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm}
\begin{landscape}
\center \textbf{\large{Month}}
\\
\hrulefill
\\
\textbf{\large{\center Title1}}
\\
\hrulefill
\\
\large{\center Titl1}
\input{table_factories_bengali.tex}
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\[-.5em]
  \textbf{Name1} & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ৪ \\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\[-.5em]
  \textbf{Name2} & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ৩.৭ \\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\[-.5em]
  \textbf{Name2} & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ০ & ৩.১ \\

\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that means that xelatex can't find the font. Show a small, complete example that shows which font you are trying to use.

Comment: I trying to use following: \usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Bangla MN}

Comment: that is not a *complete* example.

Comment: I added the complete example in the description above. Please have a look. I really appreciate your help on this. I have been stuck on this since yesterday.

Comment: That is too loong.create a new, empty test document. Copy only the document class and the polyglossia lines and the bengalifont definition. Add as document body hello world and try again.